# The ZipInputStream can't read all information of zip file

Tags: java, zipinputstream

I wrote some code using `ZipInputStream` but there is something wrong with it.

```
ZipInputStream zin=null;
zin=new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
    new FileInputStream("e:/testzip.zip")));
ZipEntry ze;
while((ze=zin.getNextEntry())!=null) {

     System.out.println("readfile"+ze.getName());

     int c=0;

     while((c=zin.read())>0) {
       System.out.write(c);
     }
 }
 zin.close();
```

There are 3 text files in the `testzip.zip`. That is, the right output should be the three file names and their contents.  However, my output are 3 file names and 2 of their contents. Why only 2 contents, rather than 3?

Comment: You might not be a native speaker of English, but it is important to understand the difference between 'read' and 'write'.  (It is not possible to write to an input stream, only read from it.)  2) Please take more care typing posts, use the code formatting button at the top of the message posting/editing form, and leave out extraneous blank lines from code postings. -- And, welcome to SO!

Comment: You're welcome for the edit & any tips I can provide.  :)

Comment: I edited my answer and wrote you a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a zip with 3 textfiles in; the fact that they are textfiles is important for the following code to work. I read all entries and write out it's names and contents:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("D:\\zip.zip");
        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
        while(entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            ZipEntry zipEntry = entries.nextElement();
            System.out.println(zipEntry.getName());
            BufferedReader bufferedeReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry)));
            String line = bufferedeReader.readLine();
            while(line != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                line = bufferedeReader.readLine();
            }
            bufferedeReader.close();
        }
        zipFile.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: are you sure the third file isn't empty ?

Comment: yeah .I'sure.I check the zip file more than 5 times

Comment: @WillYu Nevertheless the suggested amendment is correct. Your original code would treat a NUL byte in the input as end of file, which is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For this use case, it seems like [ZipFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) might be more appropriate, since that can give you the zip file's TOC.